# Java library for integrating with external Storage providers

Tags: java, amazon-s3, mediastore, cloudify

I'm about to integrate Cloudify in my webapp to handle media storage.

I was wondering if a java library already exist that abstracts data access/storage and can handle different storage providers like S3, Cloudify etc.

Answer (score 0):

jclouds (https://jclouds.apache.org/)  support an abstraction for data access, called BlobStorage. Have a look at the list of providers here:

http://jclouds.apache.org/guides/providers/#blobstore-providers